# RegQueryValueEx returns 0x02 while trying to read registry key?

Tags: c++, registry

i'm trying to read the graphics card used by the system from the registry. Therefor i'm accessing the registry with the szRegKey/szSubKEy listed below.

The RegQueryValueEx exits with Error 0x02 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

If i'm trying to access the key via the cmd with `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winsat" /v PrimaryAdapterString` it succeeds succesfully. Can you help me with my problem?

```
HKEY hKey;
WCHAR szRegKey[]= L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winsat";

WCHAR szSubKey[] = L"PrimaryAdapterString";

WCHAR *buf;
DWORD dwBufSize = 0;
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;

if(RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, szRegKey, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    return false;
}

if(RegQueryValueExW(hKey, szSubKey, 0, &dwType, NULL, &dwBufSize) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You might need some more permissions, like enumeration of values.  Try with `KEY_READ`...

Comment: Standard mistake is trying to read registry keys on a 64-bit version of Windows with a 32-bit process.  You will need to include the KEY_WOW64_64KEY option in the *samDesired* argument to state that you explicitly want to access 64-bit keys.  Or build a 64-bit program of course, few reasons left to not do that anymore.